# android: test app on a real device

Tags: android, testing

My client wants to dogfood my android app. They don't have eclipse and don't want to install it. Is there a more convenient way to send my apk to them? Can I send it via email and let them open the attachment in mobile device? Will it start installing itself automatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Upload the APK to a Web site, configure the Web server to serve `.apk` files with the [proper MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29), and send the URL to the tester via an email, SMS, tweet, etc.

Comment: The MIME-type step is not required.  Just uploading the APK to a web site (or really, web *server*) of any description is sufficient.  There should be no need to mess with the server configuration.

Comment: @aroth: That may be a relatively recent development.

Answer (score 4):

CommonsWare's answer is a great way to do it.  Another way that I've used in the past to get a few people to beta test my apps is have them put the apk file on the phone's SD card.  Then use an app like Astro File Manager to browse to the file and install it.

I've also had a few other developers email me their APK files to test, and this is the method I used to install their apps on my phone.  Note that I'm just opening the email on my PC, and saving the attachment to the SD card on the phone via USB.

Answer (score 4):

This thread is pretty old, but I thought I would add:

Try dropbox app. Create a shared folder and configure the device so it can access that folder then your client can install it directly on the device by navigating to the APK and opening it.

Answer (score 3):

Crazy as this sounds, I use my Dropbox public folder to send a URL that would initiate an OTA installation on the phone.

I just drop my .APK file into my Dropbox public folder, get its public URL and use an online service like [kaywa.com](http://qrcode.kaywa.com/) to generate a QR code for that URL and send it via email or IM.

It's quick and easy (not to mention, absolutely free).

Answer (score 2):

I've never sent an APK as an attachment (I normally send a link to an APK on the internet) but I expect it would work. Just click to open it, and you well get the same prompts about permissions that you get in the Market application.

The APK does need to be signed though (this can easily be done in Eclipse with Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package). Also make sure `android:debuggable="false"` is set in your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The email approach may only work if the email client knows about the MIME type for APK files, which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Using the default google mail application on an android phone you have the option to preview attached files, however no option to save them. Attempting to preview the attatched apk file will launch the package installer but it will fail with "There is a problem parsing the package".

Tested on my phone with android 1.5 (the apk will install if transfered via usb)

Answer (score 1):

I always used this [app](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.jp-co-taosoftware-android-attachapkinstaller-qxAp.aspx). Worked flawlessly every time.

Answer (score 0):

this post is old but i think i should just add this:
use hockey app: http://hockeyapp.net/ its a great platform for managing tests and versions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks. HockeyApp is a platform for testing app: 

HockeyApp is a great way to collect live crash reports, get feedback from your users, distribute your betas, and analyze your test coverage.
The website as at the time of writing is: http://hockeyapp.net/