# How do I export an apk signed with the debug certificate?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

The Android Tools menu in Eclipse only lets me export an unsigned apk, or one signed with my release cert. I need the debug-certificate-signed apk that Eclipse creates when I debug my Android app.

Where is it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you need a version of the apk signed with the debug certificate?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The compiled APK (with debug key) is found at the /bin folder in you eclipse project

Comment: Alternatively, your debug key file is located at ~/User folder in OSX or Windows (your root user folder) - its hidden so you'll need to enable viewing hidden files

Comment: I know it is supposed to be in /bin, but it isn't there. :(

Comment: Try Project -> clean. Make sure build automatically is set and run the project. After you run it the file should be there..

Comment: Anyway - a path to the debug.keystore is located here:
eclipse -> prefrences -> android -> build

Answer (score 0):

I found the complete details (including passwords) in the SDK docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode