# Newbie help for installing app on Android device

Tags: android

I'm working on developing my first mobile app on the Appery.io platform. I'm just about done building the app and need to beta test it for Android.

Appery lets you generate an Android certificate and export your app as a .apk file. I have my .apk file and I want to install it on my friend's phone. Is there anything else I need to do or can I install the .apk file? How do I go about actually getting it installed on the phone? It's not clear from the site's instructions how to do it when using a platform that generates the .apk file for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Deploy Android Application to Beta Tester Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122322/how-to-deploy-android-application-to-beta-tester-devices)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to email the APK file to your friend. Then click on the attachment on your friend's phone. Alternatively, you can install the Android SDK and use its `adb` tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it via Bluetooth or Share it on Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. When you install the app be sure that in the phone settings the "Install apps from unknown publisher" is checked. And don't verify the app with google play. Just click package installer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to install apk like:

1. send apk as attachment to your friend and open the attachment on their device.
2. copy the apk to their device and open it using any file manager, it will lead to install it.
3. send apk whiya bluetooth/ wifi tethering etc and open it on their device.
4. upload it to any file hosting website and open that link in their device using any web browser and download and install further.
5. if that device is with you, you can use [adb.exe tool](http://adbshell.com/download/download-adb-for-windows.html) with following command "adb install your apkfile"

Note: but to use any of these ways, their device should have enabled "Install from Unknown sources" in their device settings->security.

Or alternately best approach:

1. upload your apk to GooglePlay Store and they can install it from there hassle free.